# Python: How to find all combinations of a list when changing only specific elements

Tags: python, list, loops, recursion, python-itertools

Using python I am trying to find all combinations of a list by changing only specific elements in it. For example, if I have a list `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]` and append 3 strings to it, I would have:

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,'string','string','string']
```

I would then like to find all combinations the list can take when only the position of the strings are allowed to change.

e.g

```
[1,2,3,4,5,'string',6,7,8,9,'string','string']
[1,2,'string',3,4,5,'string',6,7,'string',8,9]
['string',1,'string',2,3,4,'string',5,6,7,8,9]
```

etc, whilst still keeping the original list of numbers in the same ascending order. 
I am not necessarily trying to store every simple combination at once, I am just trying something like:

- Iterate through all of the possible combinations
- For each possibility, check a condition
- If true, then assign the list to a variable
- If false, then continue iterating

I have been trying to find a solution without having to use an unreasonable amount of for loops and which would be applicable to larger lists with possibly more strings appended. I have been looking at using itertools but can't seem to find an approach.

A solution I found could be to just use `itertools.permutations` (list with appended strings), and then use conditions to check if the numbers are in ascending order, but I was worried this approach would be really inefficient and take up heaps of memory, especially when working with larger lists.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: One approach might be to treat the positions as indexes, get all the 3-long permutations of the indexes, then create the lists on demand (if needed) by inserting the strings.

Comment: Are the strings allowed to be reordered relative to each other?

Comment: yep you can reorder the strings

Answer (score 3):

I guess you could do something in the line of the comments by @wjandrea:

```
from itertools import combinations, permutations

lst = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]

strings = ['foo', 'bar', 'foobar']

for positions in combinations(range(len(lst) + len(strings)), len(strings)):
    for permutation in permutations(strings, len(strings)):
        cop = lst[:]
        for string, pos in zip(permutation, positions):
            cop.insert(pos, string)
        print(cop)
```

**Output** (small sample)

```
['foo', 'foobar', 1, 2, 3, 'bar', 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
['bar', 'foo', 1, 2, 3, 'foobar', 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
['bar', 'foobar', 1, 2, 3, 'foo', 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
['foobar', 'foo', 1, 2, 3, 'bar', 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
['foobar', 'bar', 1, 2, 3, 'foo', 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
['foo', 'bar', 1, 2, 3, 4, 'foobar', 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
['foo', 'foobar', 1, 2, 3, 4, 'bar', 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Note that this solution assumes that you can *reorder* the strings.

Comment: wow, thank you the quick response, this was what I was looking for

Comment: Calling `list.insert` in a loop is inefficient.

Comment: @DanielMesejo You can refer to my answer for a more efficient implementation.

Answer (score 2):

@DanielMesejo's answer works but uses the `list.insert` method to insert each string into its position in a copy of the number list, which is inefficient since `list.insert` takes an average time complexity of *O(n)* per iteration.

A more efficient way to construct each list according to the combination of positions and permutation of strings is to use a dict that maps positions to the strings, then iterate the position over the total length, and if the position is in the said dict, output the string at that position; otherwise output the next number in the list by using an iterator.

For even better efficiency, you can use `itertools.product` over the two generators of `combinations` and `permutation` to avoid having to use a nested loop that repeatedly computes the same permutations over and over again:

```
from itertools import combinations, permutations, product

lst = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
strings = ['foo', 'bar', 'foobar']

total_len = len(lst) + len(strings)
for positions, permutation in product(combinations(range(total_len), len(strings)),
                                      permutations(strings, len(strings))):
    string_pos = dict(zip(positions, permutation))
    numbers = iter(lst)
    print([string_pos[i] if i in string_pos else next(numbers) for i in range(total_len)])
```

Comment: Yep, this is faster.

Answer (score 1):

You can use recursion with a generator:

```
data, s = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9], ['foo', 'bar', 'foobar']
def groups(d):
   if all(i in d for i in s):
     yield d
   else:
     for i in range(len(d)):
       for k in filter(lambda x:x not in d, s):
          yield from groups(d[:i]+[k]+d[i:])

result = [*set(map(tuple, groups(data)))]
```

Output:

```
[(1, 2, 3, 4, 'foo', 'foobar', 5, 'bar', 6, 7, 8, 9), 
 (1, 'foo', 'foobar', 2, 'bar', 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9), 
 (1, 'foobar', 2, 3, 'bar', 4, 5, 6, 'foo', 7, 8, 9), 
 ('bar', 'foo', 1, 2, 'foobar', 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9), 
 (1, 2, 'foobar', 3, 4, 5, 6, 'bar', 'foo', 7, 8, 9), 
 (1, 2, 3, 'foo', 'foobar', 4, 5, 6, 'bar', 7, 8, 9), 
 (1, 'bar', 2, 3, 'foo', 4, 5, 6, 7, 'foobar', 8, 9), 
 (1, 2, 3, 'foobar', 4, 5, 'bar', 6, 7, 'foo', 8, 9), 
 (1, 2, 3, 'foo', 4, 5, 6, 'foobar', 'bar', 7, 8, 9), 
 (1, 'foobar', 2, 3, 4, 'bar', 5, 'foo', 6, 7, 8, 9)
 ...
 ]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with backtracking. At each step in a path, we either append a number or a string (a path, therefore, is a series of decisions). If we reach the end of a path, we append a copy of that path to the result.

We can apply this approach to all permutations of a the `strings` list to get our final answer:

```
from itertools import permutations

def combinations(nums, strings):
    res = []

    def generate(i, j, string_combo, path):
        if i == len(nums) and j == len(strings):  # path ends
            res.append(path[:])
            return
        if i < len(nums):  # choose number
            path.append(nums[i])
            generate(i + 1, j, string_combo, path)
            path.pop()
        if j < len(strings):  # choose string
            path.append(string_combo[j])
            generate(i, j + 1, string_combo, path)
            path.pop()

    for p in permutations(strings):
        generate(0, 0, p, [])
    return res

result = combinations([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], ['A', 'B', 'C'])
print(len(result))  # 1320
```

The time complexity of this approach is *O(s! (n + s) 2 <sup>(n + s)</sup>)*. This is because there are *s!* permutations of the string list, and for each we backtrack. The length of each path is *(n + s)* and we make 2 operations per step and a copy at the end.